# Cannot create an instance of an abstract class (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

Trying to use LiveData but this error apears.

```
class GameViewModel : ViewModel() {
private val _score = MutableLiveData<Int>()
val score: LiveData<Int> = _score
private val _word = MutableLiveData<String>()
val word = LiveData<String> = _word
```

Comment: You have an `=` where you need a `:` on the last line.

Comment: The problem was fixed. I'm newbie in this art.